# continue playing streaming audio when app is in the background in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-mediaplayer

im building a app to stream live radio over wifi. The problem im having is how to i keep the app playing when the user minimizes the app?

```
private void initializeMediaPlayer() {


player = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    player.setDataSource("url");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
       // playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
        Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into `Service`s. They will let you do things in the background when the app minimizes.

When your app minimizes, you make an `Intent` that describes to your `Service` what is to be streamed and from what time. The `Service` will then construct a `MediaPlayer` and continue streaming. Also, a good idea would be to have a `Notification` that will let the user end this `Service` without opening the app.

One more condition is when the user maximizes the app after the `Service` has been playing for some time. In this case, you need a persistence mechanism to keep track. Like `SharedPreferences` or `SQLite`.

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your mediaplayer as a service as an Activity will be in onstop state when minimized.

```
public class MyMediaPlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {


    static MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;



    public MyMediaPlayerService() {

    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();

            mPlayer = null;
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


        }






        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {

            mPlayer.setDataSource(intent.getStringExtra("streamurl"));
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
// Request audio focus for playback


            mPlayer.prepareAsync();


        mPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        notification();


        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Live radio streaming, it's long running process irrespective of UI, so you need to implement complete  media player logic in service and your service will be take all the charge for streaming. As per as ui is concerned whatever UI component you are using to represent the streamed data can communicate with service you will implement.

And regarding start and stop streaming, it will be depend on your application design. 
I think this approach will be open for all expected application design.

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @Tech_Intelliswift- how exactly do i get started

Comment: how do i connect a Ui to a service